# Why calling Intervention\Image raised error Drivers\GD\Driver not found?

Tags: php, laravel, intervention

I installed intervention/image 3.5 on Laravel 10 app and got error :

Class "Intervention\Image\Drivers\GD\Driver" not found

With code :

```
use Intervention\Image\ImageManager;
use Intervention\Image\Drivers\GD\Driver;

class GetImageProps
{
    public static function get(string $imageType, string $imagePath = null): array
    {
        $retArray = [];
        $storageFullImagePath = base_path() . '/storage/app/' . $imagePath;
        try {
            $manager = new ImageManager(new Driver()); // Error pointing this line
            $targetImage = $manager->read($storageFullImagePath);
```

I check that package is installed ok :

```
$ composer show intervention/image
name     : intervention/image
descrip. : PHP image manipulation
keywords : gd, image, imagick, resize, thumbnail, watermark
versions : * 3.5.0
type     : library
license  : MIT License (MIT) (OSI approved) https://spdx.org/licenses/MIT.html#licenseText
homepage : https://image.intervention.io/
source   : [git] https://github.com/Intervention/image.git 408d3655c7705339e8c79731ea7efb51546cfa10
dist     : [zip] https://api.github.com/repos/Intervention/image/zipball/408d3655c7705339e8c79731ea7efb51546cfa10 408d3655c7705339e8c79731ea7efb51546cfa10
path     : /mnt/_work_sdb8/wwwroot/lar/NewsPublisher/vendor/intervention/image
names    : intervention/image

support
issues : https://github.com/Intervention/image/issues
source : https://github.com/Intervention/image/tree/3.5.0

autoload
psr-4
Intervention\Image\ => src

requires
ext-mbstring *
intervention/gif ^4.0.1
php ^8.1

requires (dev)
mockery/mockery ^1.6
phpstan/phpstan ^1
phpunit/phpunit ^10.0
slevomat/coding-standard ~8.0
squizlabs/php_codesniffer ^3.8

suggests
ext-exif Recommended to be able to read EXIF data properly.
```

In output of phpinfo :

```
PHP Version 8.2.16

gd
GD Support  enabled
GD headers Version  2.3.3
GD library Version  2.3.3
FreeType Support    enabled
```

Do I need to some options to config/app.php ?

What is wrong ?

Comment: have you done `composer dump`\ `php artisan cache:clear`?

Comment: Yes, it did not help

Comment: I have added the a correct paht, check if solves, or do like [code example](https://github.com/Intervention/image?tab=readme-ov-file#code-examples).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Although *class names in PHP* are not case sensitive, *file names on a Unix-like system are*. So when the autoloader looks for the class `Intervention\Image\Drivers\GD\Driver` it tries to open `vendor/intervention/image/src/Drivers/GD/Driver.php` but the actual file is `vendor/intervention/image/src/Drivers/Gd/Driver.php` (lower-case "d" in "Gd").

You just need to change this line:

```
use Intervention\Image\Drivers\GD\Driver;
```

to:

```
use Intervention\Image\Drivers\Gd\Driver;
```

Answer (score -3):

By the [documentantion](https://image.intervention.io/v3/basics/image-manager#create-a-new-image-manager-instance), Intervention Image is currently shipped with two different drivers. Depending on your PHP installation, you can choose between GD or Imagick.

```
Intervention\Image\Drivers\Gd\Driver
Intervention\Image\Drivers\Imagick\Driver
```

You can do in many forms of code, with this you don't need the use namespace of the driver:

```
use Intervention\Image\ImageManager;

// create new image manager with gd driver
$manager = ImageManager::gd();
```

Comment: The library provides a choice of drivers, both should work.

Comment: @IMSoP edited to not use the other driver and without need of `use`.

Comment: There's nothing wrong with the way the code was written in the OP, they just didn't notice that "Gd" needs a lower-case "d".